# Does Jmeter actually create records in the database?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I’m testing a web application with a shopping cart. I want to do a load testing using jmeter. First of all, I recorded a script for the action in which user selects an item and adds it to the shopping cart and submits and completes the order (no payment gateways involved as a testing site).  Now If I replay the script with 100 users (Thread count = 100), should it create 100 order requests in the database?

However, I didn’t see jmeter creating any multiple orders in the database in my trial rounds. There’re some failed requests as well. Is my script wrong? Should jmeter create new requests if I do the test correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script implementation is correct it should behave exactly like it would be a real user completes the order using the real browser.

The most common problem is missing or incorrectly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter). In majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script without handling dynamic parameters.

Try running your test scenario with 1-2 users and iterations and inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing.

It could also be a good idea to add [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) so JMeter would check anticipated text presence in the responses and automatically fail the requests if you've landed in the wrong page.